# StartApp ads not loading on Back Pressed in android

Tags: android, ads, startapp

i have Developed an application that have integrated with StartApp ads for the  Interstitial ads and i want to implement at onBack Pressed event so i did code like this..

code on onCreate

```
int k;
AdRequest adRequest;
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
private StartAppAd startAppAd;
private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startAppAd = new StartAppAd(this);
    StartAppAd.init(this, "104306606", "204687187");
    startAppAd.showAd();
    startAppAd.loadAd();
```

onBack Pressed

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        startAppAd.onBackPressed();
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Press Again to Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few comments regarding your integration:

1. You can't call showAd() in the onCreate method in the way you did. The reason is that there is no loaded ad to display.
   It seems like you are trying to create a splash ad, so I recommend using our splash ad feature:
   [StartApp Splash Ad](https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/Android-InApp-&-InApp-Plus-Documentation#step-6-showing-a-splash-ad)
2. You forgot to integrate our SDK in the onResume method of your activity. Take a look here: [Initializing the StartApp ad object](https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/Android-InApp-&-InApp-Plus-Documentation#initializing-the-startapp-ad-object)
3. Remember that loading an ad might take a while, depending on your device and network, so you should allow the app to run for a while when testing before trying to display the ad.

If you have any more questions/issues, please contact our support team at support@startapp.com

Answer (score 0):

```
`private StartAppAd startAppAd = new StartAppAd(this);`
```

Try to define the variable while declaring. I had few other problems as well, this solved it. 
Anyway I only used simple implementation of onBackPressed, as mentioned in the documentation.[showing-exit-ads](https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/Android-InApp-Documentation#showing-exit-ads)

Answer (score 0):

**Late answer, but it might help others who have the same issue**

I had the same issue, since StartApp's documentation is not descriptive enough in some places.

**Showing Exit Ads**

***Initialize the StartApp Ad Object (In Activity or Fragment)***

```
private StartAppAd startApp = new StartAppAd(this);
```

***Now override onResume() and onPause() methods***

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startAppAd.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    startAppAd.onPause();
}
```

***Finally in your onBackPressed() method***

```
@Override
protect void onBackPressed() {
    startAppAd.onBackPressed();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

*The thing is StartApp hasn't given documentation on overriding onResume() and onPause() method. Without this step, the exit ads won't be shown.*